# my background is becoming pink

Tags: texturing

heres the issue- the image shown is in rendered mode and in material mode the background IS visible
[image: problem image attached]

Comment: blender usually shows pink if it is not able to find a texture for the object. are you using an hdri?

Comment: no i am using a normal picture since the hdri isnt correctly positioned